# Reverse engineering base class definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In one of the puzzles I'm solving now there is a task to determine the base class for the class below

```
class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    result(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        return 100 - this.a + this.b;
    }
}
let m = new MyClass();
m.result(10, 20) === 90;
m.result(20, 10) === 110;
```

I don't need ready solving, I need an explanation how can I get possible base class definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be this:

```
class BaseClass {
  set a(v) { this._a = 30-v }
  get a( ) { return this._a }

  set b(v) { this._b = 30-v }
  get b( ) { return this._b }
}
```

or this:

```
class BaseClass {
  set a(v) { this._b = v }
  get a( ) { return this._a }

  set b(v) { this._a = v }
  get b( ) { return this._b }
}
```

There are countably infinite many ways to achieve this:

```js
class BaseClass {
    constructor ( ) {
      this.i = -1;
    }
    set a(v) { this.i++; }
    get a( ) { return (2-this.i)*10 }

    set b(v) { }
    get b( ) { return (this.i+1)*10 }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    result(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        return 100 - this.a + this.b;
    }
}

let m = new MyClass();

console.log( m.result(10, 20) === 90 );
console.log( m.result(20, 10) === 110 );
```

One more example and expected output could greatly narrow down the family of solutions. The first and second example I gave behave differently from each when other numbers are provided, and the third one depends on the number of times `result` has been called rather than the arguments passed into to it.

Comment: Since this is a puzzle, the solution may be neat or intuitive. There's a good chance it's `set a(v) { this._a = -v }` `set b(v) { this._b = -v }`, at least it should be tried among the first ones. Otherwise there's infinite amount of possible solutions, of course.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `Object.getPrototypeOf`, e.g.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(MyClass) === BaseClass
```

ES6 class syntax sets the resulting constructor's `[[Prototype]]` to the parent class.